# Store Live WebRTC Video in YouTube

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, streaming, webrtc

I have a WebRTC application which I am using for video chat.

I need to provide a 'Store video' button which basically takes the user's stream and stores it in YouTube. I have tried live streaming as well as video upload APIs of YouTube but somehow they are not working.

Am I using the correct approach? Between live streaming and video upload which is correct to use? Is there some other way I can store this?

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to store WebRTC video on youtube:

1) Record the WebRTC stream in a file mp4 or webM and upload this file on youtube using an youtube API.

2) Convert the WebRTC stream in real-time to RTMP H.264+AAC and push the result stream to youtube how it does an RTMP live encoder.

Comment: Thanks @Alex
I've achieved the first point, but hit a road block. I think the solution would be your second point, but I'm not able to send a live stream to a rtmp server. YouTube api doesn't tell me how to do that. It just says,
Step 3.2: Start your video

Start transmitting video on your video stream.

But how do I start transmitting the video, I'm not able to figure that out. Please help me with some examples if possible.

Comment: I've the rtmp server and stream Id from the youtube api, but how do i use these to transmit a stream to that youtube rtmp server.

Comment: You can push an RTMP stream to Youtube in H.264 + AAC format from an RTMP client (Live encoder with RTMP support). The same you can do with your WebRTC server if it works in client mode and allows to re-publish WebRTC stream as RTMP. So the scheme is **WebRTC browser** >> [WebRTC]  >> **WebRTC server** >> [RTMP] >> **RTMP Server** >> [RTMP]  >> **Youtube**